# Changed WS address and I don't know to update it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I work with asp pages and `.net 2.0 framework`.

A company changed his WebService url where a lot of site (created by previous programmers in the past years) connect to. 
Now I need to modify this url to connect correctly but I don't know any idea to do that!

I saw the dll invoked placed in

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

but I don't have the source code of it.
I tried to found them (cs, csproj, config ecc files) but nothing.... there aren't in all C and D.

Thanks for your help!!

Francesco

Comment: Normally this configuration will be in the web.config file which you can find in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

Comment: Thanks Bayeni! I saw in this path and there are the folder C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727 Empty and another folder called Dll. In this one there is a folder with the name of my dll which includes many files: other dll, pdb, xml, config,tlb ecc. I tried to modify the url included in the file myNameDll.dll.config (which contains the web service url to connect), but it seems don't work since when I invoke the Web Service it "calls" the old url.  Thanks a lot 4 your support. Best regards. Francesco.

Comment: If you find you can't work out where the URLs are coming from, you can always try a decompiler like [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: Thanks Simon MᶜKenzie. Yes, I found the dll.config (I opened it with a text pad) and in the tag where is the URL I substituted the new one. I need to recompile the dll maybe? I thought, since I modified just a config file, it wasn't necessary to recompile the dll. How do you think about it? Thanks!

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you want to change an application say A which connect to the web service B that changed its URL. 

Say B's URL was http://servername/yourName.asmx and it changed to http://servername2/yourName.asmx, now you want to change A to point to B's new url. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes bayeni. My Asp page calls this Web Service (actually at http:\\oldUrl_wsld) and now this url it's changed by the owner of the Service in http:\\newUrl_wsdl. I saw that http:\\oldUrl_wsld is "mapped" in mynamedll.dll.config (which is a similar wml file) so I change the url in this file but i suspect is not enough.

Comment: The settings are always read from `web.config`, not the `dll.config`. Try copying your config settings from your `dll.config` into your `web.config`.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Since I inherited all site, I wouldn't change nothing about Dll's system because I don't know the effects that I could produce. So I would ask you if I can get the source of the Dll (since I have it) with the program you told me... DotPeek. Thanks a lot for your support.... anything can help me. Regards

Comment: Maybe I'm near the solution thanks your helps. I decompiled (Export to Project with JetBrains) the Dll and in Visual Studio I found the URL (old) in this path: NameProject.csproj->Properties->Settings.cs. In the code there is  [DefaultSettingValue("https://NameService/XXX/YYY/CustomerWS")].  So I need to modify and recompile this or I can made the changes also without modifing the dll? Thanks again!